# Use the ColumnAttribute or the HasKey method to specify an order for composite primary keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, database-migration

I'm trying to use composite primary key on 2 objects with parent-child relationship. Whenever I try to create a new migration, I get an error:

**Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'Models.UserProjectRole'. Use the ColumnAttribute or the HasKey method to specify an order for composite primary keys.**

As per error suggests, I do add annotation `Column (Order = X)` but the error still there and does not go away, unless I leave only one field with Key annotation. 
Here  is my object that it trips off:

```
public class UserProjectRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0),DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserProjectRoleID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column (Order = 1)]
    public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectID")]
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public Guid AppUserGuid { get; set; }

    // followed by a number of unrelated String fields.
 }
```

Here is Project class:

```
public class Project: Base
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProjectRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    // followed by a number of unrelated String fields.

}
```

Here is part of my DBContext:

```
public class SiteContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserProjectRole> UserProjectRoles { get; set; }
}
```

I'm in VisualStudio 2012 with EF 4.3.1

I have been banging my head against this for a while now and all the forum and SO answers suggest to add Column Order annotation that I already have.
**Am I missing something obvious???**

*Thank you for reading this far -)*

Comment: Did you try `HasKey` with Fluent API? I'm wondering if the problem is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979581/ef-4-1-entitytype-has-no-key-composite It's said there that annotations didn't work but Fluent API. Nevertheless the annotations you have applied should work imo. Is it Code-First with no connection string or a connection string without EDM sections?

Comment: @Slauma No, I did not try fluent configuration. But I did find the solution that was with EF and .Net versions: Column attribute was moved to different namespace and not being picked up in .Net 4.5. See my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It took a lot of fiddling about and testing different things. I was clueless until I decided to make a new vanilla project with the similar data structure from scratch.
And when I installed EntityFramework from NuGet, I was shown a message:

> ### Known Issues with Entity Framework 4.x and .NET Framework 4.5
>
> Entity Framework 4.1 thru 4.3 included additional data annotations in
>   the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace in the
>   EntityFramework assembly. In .NET 4.5 these annotations were moved to
>   be part of the .NET Framework in the
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace of the
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly. If you are using
>   EF 4.x and targeting .NET 4.5 this results in two data annotations
>   with the same name in different assemblies. Because the annotations in
>   the .NET Framework are in a different namespace we were not able to
>   use type forwarding to avoid this conflict.
>
> It is possible to use EF 4.x on .NET 4.5 but we recommend using the
>   latest pre-release version of EF 5. If you are not using the affected
>   data annotations there is no impact on your code. If you are using the
>   data annotations in a C# project you can use the extern modifier to
>   ensure your code uses the annotations from EntityFramework.dll
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5(v=VS.80).aspx). If
>   you use the new annotations from the
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly in .NET 4.5 they
>   will not be processed by Code First.
>
> The affected annotations are:
>
> - **Column**
> - ComplexType
> - DatabaseGenerated
> - DatabaseGeneratedOption
> - ForeignKey
> - InverseProperty
> - MaxLength
> - MinLength
> - NotMapped
> - Table

At that point I realised that my data project was freshly created in VS2012 and was by default targeting .Net 4.5 and the rest of my project in solutions were migrated from VS2010 and targeting .Net 4.0. 
So I have updated all the projects to target .Net 4.5 and got the pre-release of EntityFramework 5.0.

**Make sure you update your projects first to Net4.5, after that do update EF to 5.0, otherwise it will hate you forever and many bunnies will die.**

[This screencast](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/video-entity-framework-5-enums-and-moving-solution-from-ef-4-3/) is a great starter for updating to EF5.0

<strike>At that point my error was gone, but I was getting different one. I could not add migration because it could not find Migration Configuration, even though I had configuration set up just seconds before it.
That again took a lot of fiddling with NuGet, uninstalling ad re-installing packages. 
Then I saw in packages.config lines like this:</strike>

```
package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0-rc" targetFramework="net40"
```

I have changed targetFrameworkto "net45" and now I'm getting the expected behavior from migrations. I guess there would be a better way to get nuget target .Net 4.5 with packages, but that's what worked for me.

I hope this will save somebody banging their head on a wall.

Comment: @Slauma please see the update. If you ever have to do the update to EF5.0, make sure you do update your projects to Net4.5 BEFORE

Comment: Im in the situation that we updated to EF 5.0 (or rather 4.4) before we updated to .Net 4.5 and Alot of bunnies did indeed die. Still working on trying to get the damn shit to work one day later.

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen emm.. once you know what is broken - it is easier. We have upgraded our product to EF5 without going to .Net 4.5. And there was not much trouble. Sorry to hear about your bunnies -(

Comment: Perfect Trailmax - this is still an issue. I had upgraded a dll library to .Net 4.5 and that brought the troubles. I had to remove EF 6.1.3 with Nuget and put it back on - and its working now.

Answer (score 10):

```
public class UserProjectRole
{
   [Key, Column (Order = 0)]
   public Guid UserProjectRoleID { get; set; }

   [Key, Column (Order = 1)]
   [ForeignKey("Project")]
   public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public Project Project { get; set; }

   public Guid AppUserGuid { get; set; }

   // followed by a number of unrelated String fields.
}

public class Project: Base
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProjectRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    // followed by a number of unrelated String fields.

}

public class SiteContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserProjectRole> UserProjectRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Try this, especially with the `[Required]` above the `public Project Project {get; set;}`.

If this doesn't work, try it again and remove the `[Key, Column (Order = 1)]` above the `[ForeignKey("ProjectID")]`

Comment: @trailmax Thanks, didn't notice.

Comment: This solution helped me, thanks for posting.  ps. It's very helpful to post alternative solutions to problems, even if they're old and solved before.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the fix for those with dead bunnies (having updated to EF 5.0 before updating to .Net 4.5):

In the csproj files, change

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

TO

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Pretty obvious when you know it....

Comment: good work. Let people know! Poor bunnies, those who did not manage to escape!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come to the same solution using

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/11/entity-framework-6-alpha2-now-available.aspx