# Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

> {"Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type
>   'Conference_Project.Models.Login'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method
>   (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an
>   order for composite primary keys."}

```
 [Table("ConferenceLogin")]
public class Login
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long confid { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string emailID { get; set; }       
    [Key]
    public string registration { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public long regNo { get; set; }        
}
```

[image]

```
Version Used : EntityFramework.6.1.3  And MVC5
```

I want unique value for this (`emailID` , `registration` , `regNo` ) for that 
set all as primary key then EntityFramework showed error

how to use multiple primary key with EntityFramework?

Comment: *how to use multiple primary key with EntityFramework?* Click and read the links in the exception message.

Comment: Have you want to create n:n (many-to-many) relationship between tables with Code First (show all tables related with it)? Usually `HasKey` before `CreateModel()` used like this: `builder.Entity<ForeignTablePropertyName>().HasKey(p => new { p.emailID, p.registration, p.regNo });`.

Comment: solution already available in my error link its only need to set  [Column(Order = 1)]  order number

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910962/use-the-columnattribute-or-the-haskey-method-to-specify-an-order-for-composite-p

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although I'm not sure as to the underlying logic why this error occurs, I did have the same issue with a project I was working on for class. What worked for me was to add a Column(order) decorator to the Key tag turning

```
[Key]
```

into

```
[Key, Column(Order = n)]
```

where n is the 0-based index of the key in question.

In this light, your class should look like the following:

```
[Table("ConferenceLogin")]
public class Login
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long confid { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string emailID { get; set; }       
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string registration { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public long regNo { get; set; }        
}
```

Hope this works for you as well as it did for me!

Answer (score 0):

To set that **registration**  column as primary key, you have to set the data type nvarchar(50),. 
nvarchar(128) will not allow you to make it primary key